# Use asp.net authorize in .net core

Tags: asp.net, .net

i want to know asp.net authorize function can it be used in .net core?
Or something can instead  in  authorize for .net core? thanks

Comment: Could you explain more about your project

Comment: asp.net mvc can use authorize  to prevent user go to main page directly before login.i want to use this function in .net core mvc but no idea. /3\thxthx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` with `Identity Server 4` to authorize your application.

The tutorial from MS is [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

In short, you can change Authentication to `Individual User Accounts` when create new projects. Or you can [scaffold Identity into an exist project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

For example, you can scaffold Identity into an empty project:

> - From **Solution Explorer**, right-click on the project > **Add** > **New Scaffolded Item**.
> - From the left pane of the **Add New Scaffolded Item** dialog, select **Identity** > **Add**.
> - In the `Add Identity` dialog, select the options you want.
>
>   - Select your existing layout page, or your layout file will be overwritten with incorrect markup:
>
>     - `~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` for Razor Pages
>     - `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` for MVC projects
>     - Blazor Server apps created from the Blazor Server template (`blazorserver`) aren't configured for Razor Pages or MVC by default. Leave the layout page entry blank.
>   - Select the **+** button to create a new **Data context class**. Accept the default value or specify a class (for example, `MyApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext`).
> - Select **Add**.

Then generate Identity database schema:

```sh
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
Add-Migration CreateIdentitySchema
Update-Database
```

Comment: thank you for your advise. let me try try.thanks!^^

Comment: @ericso I noticed you are come from HK so my blog for Blazor Identity in Chinese [here](https://blog.dctewi.com/post/blazor-webassembly-hosted-with-identity/) may helps XD

Comment: That’s great, thank you for your sharing!